# How to properly design my models for likes?

Tags: django, django-models

The requirement is simple. Logged in users can like post and the likes increases by 1.

Here I think below models fulfill the requirement but I want the best database design possible.

Or there might be other best options also.

```
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

OR

```
class Like(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 2):

They're basically the same thing.

If you don't specify a [`through=` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on a ManyToManyField, Django creates a 3-column (`id`, `fk1`, `fk2`) table behind the scenes, practically exactly like your Like model (though with an added unique constraint over the two columns).

Setting a `through=` model on the M2M field makes the connection explicit and Django won't create the model for you:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='myapp.Like')


class Like(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = [('post', 'user')]
```

This is useful if you'd like to e.g. store the time a like was created:

```
class Like(models.Model):
  time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

For performance reasons, I would also recommend adding a "cache" field for the number of likes on the `Post` model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I didn't get exactly about `cache` field. Can you please add more on this with the answer.

Comment: Why is there a M2M field and not FK?

Comment: @Hills A post can be liked by multiple people.